# What is the 'best' Content Management System for low visits?

Tags: content-management

I need to build a website that keeps the content & appearance themes separate. I figured that a content management system is the best way to achieve this goal. I expect the user base to be hundreds of hits a day.
What is the best content management system for:

- Speed (given the low visits)
- Development & maintenance (cost of hiring developers & maintaining the system, ability to upgrade to new versions of the system while keeping my customized code separate)
- Availability of free themes

Comment: which OS? written in which language? do you have any restriction on anything? There are quite a couple of freebie CMS based on PHP + MySQL + Apache, for instance, WordPress and Joomla!

Comment: I use Linux as my OS. I am language agnostic: familiar with Python, PHP, Ruby, C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check some of these babies out.

- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) or [Joomla!](http://www.joomla.org/) (if you're on PHP)
- [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) (if you're on .NET)
- [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) (if you're using Python)
- [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org/) (if you're on Ruby)

Comment: Thank you. I was familiar with the existence of Django-CMS; didn't know about Pinax. I'll check it out.

Comment: If you're on Linux and are familiar with PHP, I'd personally lean into Joomla! or Wordpress.  They are very widely supported and have lots of added goodies.

Comment: Any opinions on Drupal? Have you used Pinax & Radiant? Any experience that you can share?

Comment: I've used Drupal a little bit. It is widely used in large installations. I worked on the university of Calgary drupal site ( http://ucalgary.ca ), and found it more difficult than Joomla, but far more powerful.

Comment: I have not personally used Pinax or Radiant, I've just read that they're good.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have had good success with [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/). Wordpress is also good but I have seen some people have a harder learning curve with it than with Joomla.

Comment: How is the speed of Joomla? I was wondering if it is too bloated, making it slower than alternatives for my simple requirements.

Comment: I have never felt that Joomla was bloated or slow as long as you don't load a tone of ad-ons(true of most cms systems). I have sometimes felt that Wordpress is too bloated out of the box especially on shared hosting servers with limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

I've good experience working with these **CMS** tools:

- Adobe AEM CQ5
- Interwoven HP TeamSite
- Interwoven HP LiveSite
- SharePoint

These tools are really good and have almost all the features related to Ease of use, less coding or one time design, compatibility, faster development, Good End User Experience, Targetting, Segmentation, Additional API's for integration and much more...